# Lync 2013 Microphone issue

Tags: microphone, lync-2013, skype-for-business

I am using the Microsoft Lync 2013 (Skype for Business) client. I verified my microphone and was able to test it using the SoundRecorder client. However the microphone is not recognized by the Skype client. Can someone help me to know why this might occur?

Answer (score 0):

I would check these things below

- Go to the Control Panel and make sure that none of the recording devices are muted.  Control Panel --> Sounds & Audio Devices
- Next open Skype and check that the microphone settings are correct and that nothing is muted.  Tools --> Options --> Audio Devices
- If neither of the two items above resolve the problem then try making sure that all of your drivers are up to date.

Check out [this site](http://ccm.net/faq/3675-skype-won-t-recognize-microphone) for more information.